# vBulletin Language Manager

Tags: vbulletin

i've edited default(en) vBulletin language for my own language(Turkish), but when i want to use it for my other forums with the same version(4.2.0) / when i download vbulletin-language.xml for later use, then i'm reloading it , but some phrases turn into default style although i've edited them and translated it in my language.

1-Returns default style
 2-Why its textarea is a litle long than edited ones? 
Please help i have been trying to solve this problem for days

[Screenshot]

[image]

My problem may be seen on the image above

Answer (score 1):

Go to : admincp ->  Languages and Phrases ->  Downloading and Uploading Languages

in download section choice your language and then there are 2 other options :

Include Custom Phrases AND Just fetch phrases (No language settings will be included if 'Yes' is selected)

By "language settings" we mean the settings you see when you click the [Edit Settings] link in the Language Manager. If this language is just translated phrases and no custom settings then you can select "**Yes**" here. Otherwise you should select "No" to keep the language whole as it is now.

in vbulletin main manual there are not good describe for this options : [vbulettin manual](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html?manualversion=40202500)